# How does len() function work in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In pseudocode

```
For i = 1 to Charactercount(Mymessage)
```

equal to

```
for range in (0,len(Mymessage)
```

in python or I have start from `(1,len(Mymessage)`
Please explain which one is the correct way?
Please tell how does `for i = 0 to charactercount(mymessage)-1` work ?

Comment: What do you mean? `for i = 0 to charactercount(mymessage)-1` **doesn't** work.

Comment: You're starting from 0. In the other you're starting from 1.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I meant what would be the difference between the result of -1 and without -1

Comment: @MateenUlhaq  For i = 1 to Charactercount(Mymessage) I have to write (1,len(Mymessage) in python

Comment: Ok. If that's your question, what's the code `For i = 1 to Charactercount(Mymessage)` even doing in your question? And why are asking about `(1,len(Mymessage)`? As I see it, you're asking 3 different questions here without ever explaining what your code is supposed to do. And anyway - why not just **try** it and see which code is correct?

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** because it is not useful, also it is misformatted; `for range in (0, len(Mymessage)`

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start from 0 in python, so if for example `Mymessage` has a value of `'hello'`, then `range(len(Mymessage))` will produce an iterator that counts from 0 to 4 because `Mymessage` is 5 characters long. And the following `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(Mymessage)):
    print(i, Mymessage[i])
```

will print:

```
0 h
1 e
2 l
3 l
4 o
```